# Android: How to remove rectangular corners from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

I tried this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertSeverity = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

But it says,
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder

I found other methods too, like defining the shape

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF" android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

but i don't know what Radius my corners are making. And yeah, i can make assumptions and all. But i am just asking is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: use android custom alertdialog builder

Comment: in developer.android it says, use DialogFragment to do this
but, Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.DialogFragment :/

Comment: can you post new snap shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution..

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.exitview);

Button yes_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
yes_button.setOnClickListener(this);

Button no_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
no_button.setOnClickListener(this);

dialog.show();
```

in style, same as above,

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create following style set it to your dialog background

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

For ex:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertSeverity = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Here windowBackground is the key that is removing border from dialog.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertSeverity =new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme));
```

Comment: i hate to say this but, Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder. Its just killing me. Nothings working.

Comment: well it works, i mean no error though. But it still have rounded corners. :(
I think my @android:color/transparent have some problem or so.

Comment: do you have round corners in your layout that you are setting as content view?? don't forget to upvote if my ans helped you :-)

Comment: does drawable/button1 this shape have the blue lines??